# In need for "end of block" inherent

Tags: inherent

I'm working on a wrapped chain, inspired by frontier.
We have a pallet, that contains a VM, that creates blocks that are pushed onto the outer block digest in the `on_finalize` hook.
In our block header we have a hash root of a storage structure to compute and include. The computation of this root hash is really expensive, it takes up to one-third of the block time to be done. So our idea was to compute it asynchronously for block n, while we are creating block n+1, and include the root hash of the previous block in the header of the current block.

Here is the timeline:

1. block n is finished
2. block n root hash computation start
3. block n+1 creation start
4. block n root hash computation is finished
5. block n+1 is finished, it contains block n root hash

At first, I thought I would be able to achieve this using `inherents`, the node producing the block would be able to compute the previous root hash while processing the current block transaction, and at some point, it would execute an `inherent` call in order to feed this value inside the runtime, with only minimal verification in the call itself.
It would have been the role of the verifier nodes to execute the `check_inherent` function from the `ProvideInherent` trait when they receive new blocks, before including those in their own chain state.

My problem is that since [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/8173) inherent has to be executed before any transaction (but after the `on_initialize` hook).
Given that the computation takes roughly 1/3 of a block time, it probably won't be ready on time. The block execution will be delayed until the node finishes its root hash calculation. The timeline I imagine will probably look something like this:

1. block n is received
2. block n root hash computation start
3. block n+1 `on_initialize` is executed
4. we wait more or less 1/3 of the block time
5. block n root hash is ready
6. inherent is executed
7. transaction start being processed
8. block n+1 is finished

My questions are:

- is my reasoning correct, will the root hash computation still bottleneck my block even when done in the next block as an inherent
- what are my alternatives?

A regular unsigned transaction does not seem like one, as it would require the computation to be done again in the runtime, in order to be sure that the value given is correct, and it won't be lightweight at all, so I don't see it working.
Is there a way to be a bad boy and just let my specific `inherent` be executed later?
Are off-chain workers the best solution I have?
Is there some other way for the node to inject data into the block, but near the end of it? (in the digest maybe)

EDIT:
After looking into the code I found the `EnsureInherentsAreFirst` and the code generate by `construct_runtime` that implement this trait.
Something possible would be to use `Signed` `inherents`, they would not be flaged by `FRAME` security and would still be recognized as inherent by the runtime.
Is it a good idea, to have my nodes sign such transaction?